# Concurrency with std::vector<>::size()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector

This code hangs (only in Release build, mind you) and must be terminated manually:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back( 0 );
    std::thread( [&vec]()
    {
        Sleep( 150 );
        vec.pop_back();
    } ).detach();
    while( vec.size() > 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas this code terminates naturally:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back( 0 );
    std::thread( [&vec]()
    {
        Sleep( 150 );
        vec.pop_back();
    } ).detach();
    while( vec.size() > 0 )
    {
        Sleep( 1 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that continuous spamming of `std::vector<int>::size()` is blocking execution somehow, but how and why? And why only in Release build?

(Built with VC2013, if that is a factor.)

Comment: Well, you're loosing control over a _detached_ thread.

Comment: Both your examples have undefined behavior because you have concurrent read and write access to the `vector` without any external synchronization.

Comment: This is not a factor. The thread will perform its task independently and allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits. Also, joining after the polling loop instead of detaching does not alter behavior.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes you are correct. I realize this is undefined as per the C++ standard. Still, I am interested in the mechanism of this behavior, seeing as how size() should not alter the state of container.

Comment: This is obviously a problem with optimization, but I haven't wrapped my head around exactly why yet. By the way, not that I think this is the problem, but why not use std::this_thread::sleep_for instead of a OS-specific function call?

Comment: @chris Yeah, I think something like that. Changing the sleep to asm("") gets rid of the hang too.

Comment: @tweej Mostly just habit. sleep_for does seem like a better option though.

Comment: The dissasembly for the while loop goes: test eax,eax jne -> back to test; it's not even loading from memory after the first execution of size()   :/

Comment: what about declare `std::vector` as `volatile` ?

Comment: @user1034749 I tried that, just for fun. The member functions of `std::vector` did not like it though :)

Comment: _ReadWriteBarrier() or std::atomic_thread_fence() fixes the problem (not that the code should be used in any case since the result is technically undefined.

Comment: gcc on linux doesn't even give me that chili. With O1 I get `.L82: jmp .L82` It only checks once for non-zero, and then commits to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the optimizer turns the loop:

```
while (vec.size() > 0);
```

into

```
reg = vec.size(); while(reg > 0);
```

...loading the value from `vec.size()` into a register and just reading it from there, since there is nothing in the loop that indicates a memory barrier that might cause the value to be changeable.

When you put a `Sleep` call in the loop, the call involves spilling registers, so saving the value in the register provides no benefit, so isn't done.

Answer (score 1):

The hanging code's problem is

```
while (vec.size() > 0);
```

which is the same as:

```
while (vec.size() > 0)
{
}
```

this is a tight loop continuously calling the same thing - your processor is repeatedly calling this method without doing anything else.

However, this:

```
while (vec.size() > 0) Sleep(1);
```

is telling the processor to do nothing for a millisecond (i.e. it's taking a break, likely allowing another process to run on this core in the meantime), and then calls the method again.

It's like you running as fast as you can in a non-stop sprint (hanging code), versus sprinting for a bit, then taking a moment to rest, then sprinting again, etc (non-hanging)

Comment: I believe that, regardless of the the 'tightness' of the loop, the other thread will be scheduled, either on the same processor via interruption of the main thread's execution (context switch) or on a different processor concurrently. How would 'taking a break' factor into this?

Comment: If you are referring to [Microsoft's `Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) passing in `1` is not equal to 1 second, but rather 1 millisecond

Comment: @chili - to some degree this is operating-system specific; in the hanging case, your OS may well let the 'parent' thread hog the processor, so the child never runs (if you've got a single-core machine, or if your OS insists that the detached thread runs on the same core as the parent, this isn't unlikely). In the sleep() case, the OS will yield the processor to the detached thread during the parent's sleep() (again, assuming that the detached thread is on the same core). Can you check which thread is running where?

Comment: @aho It seems the problem is with the optimization of the loop--it assumes the return value of size() will not change, and thus only performs the size() routine once. Fair enough I guess.

Comment: @chilli fair enough! makes sense too, glad you got to the bottom of it